# How to map child objects to parent from Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to to make a list of the object MyProduct  the problem is when i map the child objects to the parent object

My code looks like this

```
  ShopDatabaseEntities db = new ShopDatabaseEntities();
    var Result1 = (from Products in db.Products
                  join ProductProperties in db.ProductProperties on Products.ProductId equals ProductProperties.ProductId
                  join Properties in db.Properties on ProductProperties.PropertyId equals Properties.PropertyId

                  select new
                  {

                      Products.ProductName,
                      Products.ProductPrice,

                      ProductProperties.PropertyValue,
                      Properties.PropertyName,
                      ProductProperties.PropertyId

                  }).ToList();
    List<MyProduct> lii = new List<MyProduct>();
    foreach (var item in Result1)
    {
        MyProduct pp = new MyProduct();
        pp = (from c in Result1
              select new MyProduct { Name = item.ProductName }).First();

        MyProperty e = new MyProperty();
        e.PropertyName = item.PropertyName;
        e.PropertyValue = item.PropertyValue;

        pp.pros.Add(e);
        lii.Add(pp);
    }
```

Comment: The line `pp = (from c in Result1 select new MyProduct { Name = item.ProductName }).First();` doesn't make sense as it is functionally equivalent to `pp = new MyProduct { Name = item.ProductName };`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that this is more what you want:

```
var query =
    from Products in db.Products
    join ProductProperties in db.ProductProperties on Products.ProductId equals ProductProperties.ProductId
    join Properties in db.Properties on ProductProperties.PropertyId equals Properties.PropertyId
    select new
    {
        ProductProperties.PropertyValue,
        Properties.PropertyName,
        ProductProperties.PropertyId,
        Products.ProductName,
        Products.ProductPrice
    };

List<MyProduct> lii =
    query
        .ToArray()
        .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            x.ProductName,
            x.ProductPrice
        }, x => new
        {
            x.PropertyValue,
            x.PropertyName,
            x.PropertyId
        })
        .Select(x => new MyProduct()
        {
            Name = x.Key.ProductName,
            pros = x
                .Select(y => new MyProperty()
                {
                    PropertyName = y.PropertyName,
                    PropertyValue = y.PropertyValue,
                })
                .ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
```

---

BTW, this is the code that you should have included in your question to make answering much easier:

```
public class ShopDatabaseEntities
{
    public List<MyProduct> Products = new List<MyProduct>();
    public List<MyProductProperty> ProductProperties = new List<MyProductProperty>();
    public List<MyProperty> Properties = new List<MyProperty>();
}

public class MyProduct
{
    public int ProductId;
    public string Name;
    public string ProductName;
    public decimal ProductPrice;
    public List<MyProperty> pros = new List<MyProperty>();
}

public class MyProductProperty
{
    public int ProductId;
    public int PropertyId;
    public double PropertyValue;
}

public class MyProperty
{
    public int PropertyId;
    public string PropertyName;
    public double PropertyValue;
}
```

Type defs help immensely.

Comment: Thank you for your help ,,, but your query gets all columns and many joins i only  need the 5 columns as  my code looks, can you please tell me how to map from my result by linq ... thank you so much

Comment: Thank you , but still too much joins... My Result was only 3 joins, no way to map from my Result ?

Comment: @Lucy - There are the same number of joins as in your original query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help . yes the same joins in linq but the generated t-sql has more joins because this 

      group new
                {
                    ProductProperties.PropertyValue,
                    Properties.PropertyName,
                    ProductProperties.PropertyId
                } by new
                {
                    Products.ProductName,
                    Products.ProductPrice
                };

Comment: @Lucy - Sure,so flatten the query like you had it and then do the grouping after the `.ToArray()`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how ? i am sorry i am very very new to Linq .. that's why i am very confused

Comment: I made it,  thank you so much Enigmativity for your help :)  So is this way is a common way for mapping child to parant? Again, thank you . May all dreams come true

Comment: @Lucy - No trouble. I've also updated my answer, btw. This also isn't really mapping a child to a parent - it's just grouping - and it is very common.

Comment: Hi can you please help me to solve this problem. it's a bit similar to this one , no one can solve it so far 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027501/how-to-group-all-fields-to-object-by-linq

Comment: @Lucy - It's a very confusing question. I don't understand what you're asking. That's why you don't have any answers. Try reading [ask] and then edit your question to make it more answerable.